# How to FiX this pinescript script to show ATR trend value at close on scale?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, trendline

[image][image]I've tried multiple times but can not get the ATR trendline to show its value at the closing price on the scale. Any help or direction on how to do this would be greatly appreciated. Just trying to get cleaner entries with this script. If you notice in the pic attached the values are way before the actual close of current candle.

[image]

```
//@version=5
indicator("Trendlines with Breaks",overlay=true)
length = input.int(14)
k      = input.float(1.,'Slope',minval=0,step=.1)
method = input.string('Atr','Slope Calculation Method', options=['Atr','Stdev','Linreg'])
show   = input(false,'Show Only Confirmed Breakouts')
//----
upper = 0.
lower = 0.
slope_ph = 0.
slope_pl = 0.
src = close
n = bar_index
//----
ph = ta.pivothigh(length,length)
pl = ta.pivotlow(length,length)
slope = switch method
    'Atr'      => ta.atr(length)/length*k
    'Stdev'    => ta.stdev(src,length)/length*k
    'Linreg'   => math.abs(ta.sma(src*bar_index,length)-ta.sma(src,length)*ta.sma(bar_index,length))/ta.variance(n,length)/2*k

slope_ph := ph ? slope : slope_ph[1]
slope_pl := pl ? slope : slope_pl[1]

upper := ph ? ph : upper[1] - slope_ph
lower := pl ? pl : lower[1] + slope_pl
//----
single_upper = 0
single_lower = 0
single_upper := src[length] > upper ? 0 : ph ? 1 : single_upper[1]
single_lower := src[length] < lower ? 0 : pl ? 1 : single_lower[1]
upper_breakout = single_upper[1] and src[length] > upper and (show ? src > src[length] : 1)
lower_breakout = single_lower[1] and src[length] < lower and (show ? src < src[length] : 1)
plotshape(upper_breakout ? low[length] : na,"Upper Break",shape.labelup,location.absolute,#26a69a,-length,text="B",textcolor=color.white,size=size.tiny)
plotshape(lower_breakout ? high[length] : na,"Lower Break",shape.labeldown,location.absolute,#ef5350,-length,text="B",textcolor=color.white,size=size.tiny)
//----
var line up_l = na
var line dn_l = na
var label recent_up_break = na
var label recent_dn_break = na

if ph[1]
    line.delete(up_l[1])
    label.delete(recent_up_break[1])
    
    up_l := line.new(n-length-1,ph[1],n-length,upper,color=#26a69a,
      extend=extend.right,style=line.style_dashed)
if pl[1]
    line.delete(dn_l[1])
    label.delete(recent_dn_break[1])
    
    dn_l := line.new(n-length-1,pl[1],n-length,lower,color=#ef5350,
      extend=extend.right,style=line.style_dashed)

if ta.crossover(src,upper-slope_ph*length)
    label.delete(recent_up_break[1])
    recent_up_break := label.new(n,low,'B',color=#26a69a,
      textcolor=color.white,style=label.style_label_up,size=size.small)

if ta.crossunder(src,lower+slope_pl*length)
    label.delete(recent_dn_break[1])
    recent_dn_break := label.new(n,high,'B',color=#ef5350,textcolor=color.white,style=label.style_label_down,size=size.small)

//----
plot(upper,'Upper',color = ph ? na : #26a69a,offset=-length)
plot(lower,'Lower',color = pl ? na : #ef5350,offset=-length)

alertcondition(ta.crossover(src,upper-slope_ph*length),'Upper Breakout','Price broke upper trendline')
alertcondition(ta.crossunder(src,lower+slope_pl*length),'Lower Breakout','Price broke lower trendline')
```

Comment: what does mean : ' get the ATR trendline to show its value at the closing price on the scale' ? Can you draw us something ?

Comment: If you notice the on right hand side of the window it shows the price label of the trend line at 174.50 for the Green and 171.75 for orange. That however, is not the price for the trend lines at the close(Current Candle stick).  Those trend lines are actually 2 separate lines. One is dashed and the other is solid. All we need to do is lengthen the solid line to reach the current candle at close. This will allow the trend line label to show to correct price at close.(Current Candle.) Please let me know if this makes sense. If not I can draw something. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should record the a & b in the y = a*x + b of each line.

Then, you will be able to retrieve the value of y for the actual x=bar_index.

[image]

Here is the modified working code :

```
//@version=5
indicator("Trendlines with Breaks",overlay=true)
length = input.int(14)
k      = input.float(1.,'Slope',minval=0,step=.1)
method = input.string('Atr','Slope Calculation Method', options=['Atr','Stdev','Linreg'])
show   = input(false,'Show Only Confirmed Breakouts')
//----
upper = 0.
lower = 0.
slope_ph = 0.
slope_pl = 0.
src = close
n = bar_index
//----
ph = ta.pivothigh(length,length)
pl = ta.pivotlow(length,length)
slope = switch method
    'Atr'      => ta.atr(length)/length*k
    'Stdev'    => ta.stdev(src,length)/length*k
    'Linreg'   => math.abs(ta.sma(src*bar_index,length)-ta.sma(src,length)*ta.sma(bar_index,length))/ta.variance(n,length)/2*k

slope_ph := ph ? slope : slope_ph[1]
slope_pl := pl ? slope : slope_pl[1]

upper := ph ? ph : upper[1] - slope_ph
lower := pl ? pl : lower[1] + slope_pl
//----
single_upper = 0
single_lower = 0
single_upper := src[length] > upper ? 0 : ph ? 1 : single_upper[1]
single_lower := src[length] < lower ? 0 : pl ? 1 : single_lower[1]
upper_breakout = single_upper[1] and src[length] > upper and (show ? src > src[length] : 1)
lower_breakout = single_lower[1] and src[length] < lower and (show ? src < src[length] : 1)
plotshape(upper_breakout ? low[length] : na,"Upper Break",shape.labelup,location.absolute,#26a69a,-length,text="B",textcolor=color.white,size=size.tiny)
plotshape(lower_breakout ? high[length] : na,"Lower Break",shape.labeldown,location.absolute,#ef5350,-length,text="B",textcolor=color.white,size=size.tiny)
//----
var line up_l = na
var line dn_l = na
var label recent_up_break = na
var label recent_dn_break = na
var label rsiup = na
var label rsidown = na
var float al = na
var float bl = na
var float ah = na
var float bh = na
if ph[1]
    line.delete(up_l[1])
    label.delete(recent_up_break[1])
    
    up_l := line.new(n-length-1,ph[1],n-length,upper,color=#26a69a, extend=extend.right,style=line.style_dashed)
    y2 = upper
    x2 = n-length
    y1 = ph[1]
    x1 = n-length-1
    ah := (y2 - y1)/(x2 -x1)
    bh := y2 - ah*x2   

if pl[1]
    line.delete(dn_l[1])
    label.delete(recent_dn_break[1])
    
    dn_l := line.new(n-length-1,pl[1],n-length,lower,color=#ef5350, extend=extend.right,style=line.style_dashed)
    // y = a*x + b
    // y2 - y1 = a (x2 - x1) => a = (y2 - y1)/(x2 -x1)
    y2 = lower
    x2 = n-length
    y1 = pl[1] 
    x1 = n-length-1
    al := (y2 - y1)/(x2 -x1)
    bl := y2 - al*x2

if ta.crossover(src,upper-slope_ph*length)
    label.delete(recent_up_break[1])
    recent_up_break := label.new(n,low,'B',color=#26a69a,textcolor=color.white,style=label.style_label_up,size=size.small)

if ta.crossunder(src,lower+slope_pl*length)
    label.delete(recent_dn_break[1])
    recent_dn_break := label.new(n,high,'B',color=#ef5350,textcolor=color.white,style=label.style_label_down,size=size.small)


label.delete(rsidown)
yrsil = al*bar_index + bl
rsidown := label.new(bar_index, yrsil, text=str.tostring(yrsil, "#.####"), color=color.red, style=label.style_label_up, yloc=yloc.price)
label.delete(rsiup)
yrsih = ah*bar_index + bh
rsiup := label.new(bar_index, yrsih, text=str.tostring(yrsih, "#.####"), color=color.green, style=label.style_label_down, yloc=yloc.price)

//----
plot(upper,'Upper',color = ph ? na : #26a69a,offset=-length)
plot(lower,'Lower',color = pl ? na : #ef5350,offset=-length)

alertcondition(ta.crossover(src,upper-slope_ph*length),'Upper Breakout','Price broke upper trendline')
alertcondition(ta.crossunder(src,lower+slope_pl*length),'Lower Breakout','Price broke lower trendline')
```

Comment: See new attached price> Well thank you so much this is great. However, the label is right in the way of the price action when it crosses. Is there any way to have them show on the scale or get them out of the way of the price action somehow? I tried all of the label.set_style options.

Comment: for the label, you can place it where you want, just change the yrsil and yrsih to the value you want, you can try yrsih*1.1 for example (or yrsi+0.1 it depends on the pair you choose and its price)

Comment: I can post another question if you'd like. But I dont understand how to change the yrsil axis. I tried. Lol Also I can make another question on how to input syminfo.mintick to get a cleaner value when trading futures. Let me know and I will post those 2 questions. Big thanks!!

Comment: yes, on stackoverflow, it is better to open a new question for each problem, do not hesitate, you will get help.